# Geoserver workspace and proxy

Tags: proxy, geoserver

Can someone explain how workspace proxy works?
Whats the right configuration so I can make requests from shell (please see below)?

I have Geoserver running in a docker container and is listening in the host on port 12018.
Everything is fine accesing through the web browser.

The following URL request works on browser:

http://localhost:12018/geoserver/geonode/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=my_data_name35&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

Using typeName as geonode:my_data_name35 also works:

http://localhost:12018/geoserver/geonode/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geonode%3Amy_data_name35&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

But from cURL, the first request returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport
   version="1.2.0"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
   <ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
      Feature type :my_data_name35 unknown
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

And also from cURL, the second request returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport
   version="1.2.0"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
   <ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
      Feature type geonode:my_data_name35 unknown
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a proxy issue - please add the version of GeoServer you are using and the actual CURL commands you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, very basic actually.

The resource requested needs authentication, where the browser passes the cookie.

Using cURL, also needs to pass authentication.

It does not return forbidden maybe because some resources don't need authentication.

Sorry for the noise.